# NSMutableDictonary of NSMutableArrays of tasks for each of the next 7 days

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm, sorting, nsmutabledictionary

I have a app and the end goal is to allow users to input all their tasks. There are 2 types of tasks:

- Strict Tasks-Tasks w. Strict Start time
- Random Tasks-Tasks w. no specific start time

The end goal is that the app will automatically output all your tasks via a sectioned tableview that displays the next 7 days of the week. The app also needs to "fit" your "Random Tasks" into the gaps in your schedule.

So far I have got:

- Tasks successfully saving into SQLite
- A function that grabs "Strict Tasks" in time order(soonest first)
- A function that grabs all the "Random Tasks"
- A function that I believe will successfully sort and "fit" all the given tasks into a sorted final array.

Where I'm a bit stumped is how to go about outputting tasks in a ideal way for a sectioned tableview (I'm guessing the standard way is via a `NSMutableDictionary` of `NSMutableArrays` for each of the next 7 days), but I have no idea what the best way to go from the sorted final array from the bullet point above to the `NSMutableDictionary` of `NSMutableArrays`. Anyone have a suggestion? Feel free to scrutinize any of my steps if I'm making this more difficult than it needs to be.

ModelSingleton logic:

```
#define WhereAmI NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] "), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__);


// NOTE: This is the singleton object that the class maintains to point and hand to everyone who wants an instance of this class.  It is 'static' meaning that only one can exist throughout all versions of this class (which this forces to be only one).
static ModelSingleton * sharedInstance = nil;


@implementation ModelSingleton

#pragma mark - Singleton & Class Methods
//NOTE: This is the method you use to grab the instance of this object.
+ (ModelSingleton *)sharedInstance
{
    //Static local predicate must be initialized to 0
    static ModelSingleton *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken = 0;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[ModelSingleton alloc] init];
        // Do any other initialisation stuff here
        
        
        
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}


-(NSString *)getDBPath{
    
    
    NSString *DB_PATH = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString * path = [DB_PATH stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tasks.sqlite"];
    
    return path;
}

-(void)createDatabase{
    
    
    _db_path=[self getDBPath];
    
    NSFileManager * fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:_db_path] == NO) {
        // create it
        FMDatabase * db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:_db_path];
        if ([db open]) {
            NSString * sql = @"CREATE TABLE 'Tasks' ('TASK_ID' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , 'TASK_NAME' VARCHAR(100), 'TASK_DURATION' INTEGER,'TASK_START_TSTAMP' INTEGER)";
            BOOL res = [db executeUpdate:sql];
            if (!res) {
                NSLog(@"error when creating db table");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"succ to creating db table");
            }
            [db close];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"error when open db");
        }
    }else{
        
        [self deleteDBFile];
        NSLog(@"The file already exists");
    }
}

- (void)insertNewTask:(NSString *)taskName withDuration:(int)duration andStrictStartTime:(int)start_time {
    
    NSLog(@"FROM_MODEL_TASK_NAME:%@",taskName);
    NSLog(@"FROM_MODEL_TASK_DURATION:%d", duration);
    NSLog(@"FROM_MODEL_TASK_START_TIME:%d",start_time);
    
    _db_path=[self getDBPath];
    NSLog(@"SQLITE_PATH:%@",_db_path);
    FMDatabase * db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:_db_path];
    if ([db open]) {
        
        BOOL res = [db executeUpdate:@"insert into Tasks (TASK_NAME,TASK_DURATION,TASK_START_TSTAMP) values(?,?,?)", taskName,[NSNumber numberWithInt:duration],[NSNumber numberWithInt:start_time]];
        if (!res) {
            NSLog(@"error to insert data");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"succ to insert data");
        }
        [db close];
    }
}

-(void)clearDB{
    FMDatabase * db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:   _db_path=[self getDBPath]];
    if ([db open]) {
        NSString * sql = @"DELETE FROM Tasks";
        BOOL res = [db executeUpdate:sql];
        if (!res) {
            NSLog(@"error to delete db data");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"succ to delete db data");
        }
        [db close];
    }
    
    
    
}
-(NSMutableArray *)getTasksInTimestampOrder{
    [_tasksArray removeAllObjects];
    NSMutableArray *tasksArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    int CurrentTStamp=[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSMutableDictionary *task = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    
    [task setValue:@"Now" forKey:@"TASK_NAME"];
    [task setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:CurrentTStamp] forKey:@"TASK_START_TIME"];
    [task setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"TASK_DURATION"];
    [tasksArray addObject:task];
    
    
    FMDatabase * db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:[self getDBPath]];
    if ([db open]) {
        NSString * sql = @"SELECT * from Tasks WHERE TASK_START_TSTAMP<>0 ORDER BY TASK_START_TSTAMP ASC";
        FMResultSet * rs = [db executeQuery:sql];
        while ([rs next]) {
            int START_TSTAMP = [rs intForColumn:@"TASK_START_TSTAMP"];
            
            NSString *day=[self getDayofTheWeek:START_TSTAMP];
            
            
            int TASK_DURATION = [rs intForColumn:@"TASK_DURATION"];
            NSString * name = [rs stringForColumn:@"TASK_NAME"];
            NSLog(@"TASK_NAME:%@ | TASK_TSTAMP:%d", name, START_TSTAMP);
            
            NSMutableDictionary *task = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
            [task setObject:day forKey:@"DAY_OF_WEEK"];
            [task setValue:name forKey:@"TASK_NAME"];
            [task setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:START_TSTAMP] forKey:@"TASK_START_TIME"];
            [task setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:TASK_DURATION] forKey:@"TASK_DURATION"];
            [tasksArray addObject:task];
            
            
            
        }
        
        NSLog(@"TASKS_ARRAY:%@",tasksArray);
        [db close];
        if(tasksArray!=nil){
            return tasksArray;
        }
        
    }
    
    return nil;
    
}


-(NSMutableArray *)getRandomTasks{
    [_tasksArray removeAllObjects];
    NSMutableArray *tasksArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    
    
    
    FMDatabase * db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:[self getDBPath]];
    if ([db open]) {
        NSString * sql = @"SELECT * from Tasks WHERE TASK_START_TSTAMP=0";
        FMResultSet * rs = [db executeQuery:sql];
        while ([rs next]) {
            int START_TSTAMP = [rs intForColumn:@"TASK_START_TSTAMP"];
            int TASK_DURATION = [rs intForColumn:@"TASK_DURATION"];
            NSString * name = [rs stringForColumn:@"TASK_NAME"];
            NSLog(@"TASK_NAME:%@ | TASK_TSTAMP:%d", name, START_TSTAMP);
            
            NSMutableDictionary *task = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
            
            [task setValue:name forKey:@"TASK_NAME"];
            [task setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:START_TSTAMP] forKey:@"TASK_START_TIME"];
            [task setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:TASK_DURATION] forKey:@"TASK_DURATION"];
            [tasksArray addObject:task];
            
            
        }
        
        [db close];
        NSLog(@"TASKS_ARRAY:%@",tasksArray);
        
        if(tasksArray!=nil){
            return tasksArray;
        }
        return nil;
        
    }
    
    return nil;
    
    
}


-(void)getAndSortAllTasks{
    

    
    
    NSMutableArray *timeOrderedTasksArray=[self getTasksInTimestampOrder];
    NSMutableArray *finalSortedArray=[timeOrderedTasksArray mutableCopy];
    NSMutableArray *randomTasksArray=[self getRandomTasks];
    if(timeOrderedTasksArray!=nil){
        
        int i;
        for(i = 0;i ==timeOrderedTasksArray.count;i = i + 1)
        {
            
            NSMutableDictionary *currentTask=[timeOrderedTasksArray objectAtIndex:i];
            int currentTaskTimeStamp = [[currentTask objectForKey:@"TASK_START_TIME"] intValue];
            int taskDuration = [[currentTask objectForKey:@"TASK_DURATION"] intValue];
            int taskEndTimestamp =currentTaskTimeStamp+taskDuration;
            
            if(i+1>=timeOrderedTasksArray.count){
                if(randomTasksArray!=nil){
                    NSMutableDictionary *nextTask=[timeOrderedTasksArray objectAtIndex:i+1];
                    int nextTaskTimeStamp = [[nextTask objectForKey:@"TASK_START_TIME"] intValue];
                    
                    
                    int timeLeftBetweenTasks= nextTaskTimeStamp-taskEndTimestamp;
                    
                    NSMutableArray *updatedRandomTasks=[randomTasksArray mutableCopy];
                    int r;
                    for(r = 0;r ==randomTasksArray.count;r = r + 1){
                        NSMutableDictionary *task=[randomTasksArray objectAtIndex:i];
                        
                        int randomTaskDuration =[[task objectForKey:@"TASK_DURATION"] intValue];
                        if(timeLeftBetweenTasks<randomTaskDuration){
                            
                         
                            [finalSortedArray insertObject:task atIndex:i+1];
                            [updatedRandomTasks removeObjectAtIndex:r];
                            timeLeftBetweenTasks=timeLeftBetweenTasks+randomTaskDuration;
                            
                        }
                        
                        
                        
                        
                    }
                    
                   
                }
                
                
            }else{
                
                if(randomTasksArray!=nil){
                    for (NSDictionary *task in randomTasksArray){
                        
                        
                        [finalSortedArray addObject:task];
                        
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                
                
                
                
            }
            
            
        }
        
    }
    NSLog(@"FINAL_SORTED_ARRAY:%@",finalSortedArray);
    
}


-(NSString *)getDayofTheWeek:(int)timestamp{
    
    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timestamp];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyyMMdd";
  

    
    dateFormatter.dateFormat=@"MMMM";
    NSString * monthString = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date] capitalizedString];
    NSLog(@"month: %@", monthString);
    
    dateFormatter.dateFormat=@"EEEE";
    NSString * dayString = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date] capitalizedString];
    NSLog(@"day: %@", dayString);
    
    return dayString;
}

- (void)deleteDBFile{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *filePath = [self getDBPath];
    NSError *error;
    BOOL success = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];
    if (success) {
        
         [self createDatabase];
        
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *removeSuccessFulAlert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error:" message:@"Failed to Delete & Recreate DB" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [removeSuccessFulAlert show];
    }
}


- (NSDate *)dateByAddingOneDayFromDate:(NSDate *)date {
    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    
    NSDateComponents *plusOneDay = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [plusOneDay setDay:+1];
    NSDate *newDate = [cal dateByAddingComponents:plusOneDay
                                           toDate:date
                                          options:NSWrapCalendarComponents];
    return newDate;
}

- (NSMutableDictionary *)lastSevenDays {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
    
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSMutableDictionary *weekDays = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i <7; i++) {
        NSString *weekDay = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
        
        NSMutableArray *dayArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [weekDays setObject:dayArray forKey:weekDay];
        date = [self dateByAddingOneDayFromDate:date];
    }
    return weekDays;
}

@end
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please rephrase `Where im a bit stumped is how to go about outputting tasks in a ideal way for a sectioned tableview(im guessing the standard way is via a NSMutableDictionary of NSMutableArrays for each of the next 7 days) , but I have no idea what the best way to go from the sorted final array from the bullet point above to the NSMutableDictionary of NSMutableArrays.` and make it more understandable?

Comment: I dont know how?  I feel I was very clear.  I need to format the data so that a sectioned tableview can read it . Each section represents one of the next 7 days of the week.... Friday, Saturday, Sunday   

Each section will contain tasks.

Comment: Create a dictionary of sorted arrays - one entry for each day of the week? So dict["Monday"]=tasks for Monday and so on, then display your tableview based on today, so if today is Tuesday, put dict["Tuesday"] in the first section and so on

Comment: Yes, Paul is understanding it right. Just having trouble figuring out how to go about this.

Comment: Which part?  Your array is sorted in ascending order by date/time, so take the first entry in the array, work out what day of the week it represents, create an array, put the task in the array. Then take the next entry from your sorted array and work out its day of the week. If it is the same as the previous then add it to the array. If not then put the current array in the dictionary, keyed by the first day of the week then create a new array and put the item in that array. Repeat until you reach the end of the input array

Comment: Yeah....I think its just the whole random tasks wild card part I can sense possibly making this more difficult, but side q...how did you get so good at dev that you can give good answers around here? Just studying the Apple Documentation till you mastered it? I know my way around to build what I want but i have problems giving specific enough answers on q's around here.

Comment: Well, I started programming when I was 13, 30 odd years ago and then did a computer science degree and then worked as a programmer for 6 years. Now coding is just a hobby but yeah, writing apps, reading the documentation. Even answering questions here helps...I read up on things to find solutions for people and I learn something too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102667/discussion-between-chuckkelly-and-paulw11).

Comment: But NSDictionaries do not stay in sorted order correct?